# PDF.js: using postMessage to pass base64 to viewer.html in iframe

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm trying to create a mini-app (in Salesforce, though this may not be that relevant) that embeds the out-of-the-box `viewer.html` from PDF.js in an iframe.  Users select a PDF from a list, and the app retrieves the base64 for that PDF and passes it into the viewer.

There are working examples out there that use a dated version of the [pre-built PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/), including [this one](https://github.com/iamsonal/lwc-pdfReader) that [uses version 1.5.188](https://github.com/iamsonal/lwc-pdfReader/blob/master/force-app/main/default/staticresources/pdfjs/build/pdf.js#L31).  What these working examples appear to do is:

- [Embed the viewer](https://github.com/iamsonal/lwc-pdfReader/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/pdfGenerate/pdfGenerate.html) in an iframe and [use `postMessage`](https://github.com/iamsonal/lwc-pdfReader/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/pdfGenerate/pdfGenerate.js) to pass in a base64 to the viewer
- In `viewer.html`, the following script has been added to receive and handle the message event:

```html
<script>
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      // For standards-compliant web browsers
      window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
  } else {
      window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleMessage);
  }

  function handleMessage(evt){
    console.log('viewer.html entering handleMessage');
    var raw = atob(evt.data);
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(raw.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
      uint8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    PDFViewerApplication.open(uint8Array);
  }
</script>
```

This works fine on the dated build, but when I add the above script to `viewer.html` in the latest build (2.5.207 as of this writing), nothing happens.  `PDFViewerApplication` still exists in `viewer.js`, and still has an `open` function that takes a file as its first argument.  But when I call this function, it doesn't display my PDF.

I know [you can use the `file` parameter in the URL](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website#examples) to make the viewer display a file based on its path.  But I'm retrieving these files from a server-side REST API call, so I don't have a path, just a base64.  Is there a surefire way of getting the latest version of the viewer to receive and display a base64?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Sitting in the same Salesforce Boat and was wondering about the old howtos vs current state of affairs. Time saver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a browser caching issue.  Clearing the cache gave me the latest PDF.js library version, and I was able to view the PDF in the viewer.